# Rails 4.0 project not starting through aptana studio 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, aptana, aptana3

Currently using the Aptana Studio 3 plugin for eclipse (3.4.2) and I'm unable to start my rails 4.0 project.

Error: Ruby program /xx/xx/xx/xx/HelloRails/script/rails does not exist.

It looks like Aptana is still looking for the rails executable in script, while it moved to bin in rails 4.0. Is there any workaround/fix available for this?

Comment: I experienced the same problem and submitted a ticket in JIRA : https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8062

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a folder `script` in the root of the app and place rails file from the `bin` folder to the `script` folder then it will work.
You might need to change the web-server options in the aptana setting also.

I was having the same problem but this fix fixed it

Comment: for future reference... instead of copying the rails binary, just make a softlink (if in unix): cd project/script; ln -s /usr/bin/rails

Comment: if /usr/bin does not exist (it depends in the way you installed rails), try executing ln -s bin script from your project folder

Comment: To ensure that you are using the correct version of rails (e.g., if you are using RVM gemsets), make a symlink like this: `mkdir script; ln -s \`which rails\` script/rails`