# rails: debug rails application in eclipse / aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

I can debug one of my old application. But when I create a  new application. I tried to debug using eclipse / aptana. THe debugger didn't launch at all.

Gemfile for my old application

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem "less-rails"
gem "libv8" ,'3.16.14.3'
gem "therubyracer"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', "=2.2.6"
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'pusher'
gem 'pg'
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-rails'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Gemfile for my new application

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Something I might be missing?

Comment: Very broad question. But you might prefer using the [pry-debugger gem](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) instead of fighting with eclipse / aptana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for this post
[Rails 4.0 project not starting through aptana studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704541/rails-4-0-project-not-starting-through-aptana-studio-3)

Create a folder script in the root of the app and place rails file from the bin folder to the script folder then it will work. You might need to change the web-server options in the aptana setting also.

I was having the same problem but this fix fixed it