# Unable start server in aptana studio 3 on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I'm new to ROR development. I'm using aptana studio 3.

I've created a rails project called company.
When I try to start a server it throws a Message saying this:

```
"Error Occurred"
"Starting Server.... has encountered a problem"
"Ruby program C:\Users\kumar\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\company\script\rails does not exist."
```

How can I solve this?

Please suggest good tutorials for ROR development.

Comment: I'd try to learn one thing at a time. First, get the server working from command line. Next, learn how to use aptana (or another IDE) to do the same. when you're dealing with too many unknown factors, you are pretty much guaranteed to fail and you don't know what caused it and what to fix. Also, I am quite skeptical about using windows for rails development. Most folks use linux or mac osx.

Answer (score 3):

I too had this same issue with Aptana Studio 3, and found this answer listed in another post here:

[Rails 4.0 project not starting through aptana studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704541/rails-4-0-project-not-starting-through-aptana-studio-3)

Basically, create the "script" folder in your project and copy over the "rails" executable.