# Unable to start any debugging session in Aptana 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, aptana3

I cannot seem to launch any debugging session from within Aptana Studio 3. I click "Debug Server" but nothing shows up anywhere and nothing happens.

I have found a couple various posts, none of which actually solved my problem. I'm a noob when it comes to ruby on rails development (I'm a seasoned Visual Studio user, however) so I imagine there's something I'm doing that's dumb.

Here is my setup:

1) $ rails -v Rails 4.1.0

2) $ ruby -v 
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [x64-mingw32]

3) DevKit is installed

4) ruby-debug-ide is installed:

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.0)
actionpack (4.1.0)
actionview (4.1.0)
activemodel (4.1.0)
activerecord (4.1.0)
activesupport (4.1.0)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.6.2)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
debase (0.0.9)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.0.2)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (2.0.7)
jquery-rails (3.1.0)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (5.3.3, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.9.3)
polyglot (0.3.4)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.1.0)
railties (4.1.0)
rake (10.3.1, 0.9.6)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (4.1.1, 4.0.0)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22)
sass (3.2.19)
sass-rails (4.0.3)
sdoc (0.4.0)
sprockets (2.12.1, 2.11.0)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.9 x64-mingw32)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
turbolinks (2.2.2)
tzinfo (1.1.0)
uglifier (2.5.0)

3) Aptana Studio 3
4) Windows 7, 64-bit.

I made a quick YouTube video of me showing the issue as well as showing some locally installed gems, etc. Perhaps this reveal what I'm doing wrong.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QcK_cKYxCs&feature=youtu.be

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Rails 4.0 project not starting through aptana studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704541/rails-4-0-project-not-starting-through-aptana-studio-3)

Ooops. It was found already. The problem was my error was different (I was seeing no output); but the resolution was the same.

Basically just create a Script folder in the project directory and copy over the "rails" executable (found within your bin folder) to this directory.