# How do I create a Rails run configuration on Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on Mac OS X (High Sierra).  I have imported my Ruby on Rails project.  My Project Natures are set up like this

[image]

I want to set up my Rails server so I can run it from the IDE (or debug with it).  Oddly, the Run/Debug settings only include PHP ...

[image]

So how do I create a run configruation to run my server?  When I right click my project, select "Run As" -> "Run Configurations", I see a screen like this.  Not sure if this is the right screen to configure things or how to do it ...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your server creating a run configuration or just creating a new Rails Server.

### Creating a Run Configuration

In "**Run Configurations**" options, select `Ruby Applications > New_configuration` and then click in "**Browse...**". Type 'rails' to search for the rails file and select it inside "**Matching resources**". Click "**Ok**".

[image]

Then go to Tab "**Arguments**", set the working directory as the root folder of your project, and inside "Program Arguments" put the value "server" and click "**Apply**".

[image]

Now you can run or debug your application.

### Creating a Rails Server

Go to `Windows > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Web Servers` and click in "**New...**".

[image]

Then select the option "**Rails Server**", choose the name of your server and click "**Ok**". If your project nature was not set to "Rails" the option "Project" would be empty here, and you would need to set the Rails nature first.

[image]

If you try to run the server like this you will receive an error telling that the program ".../script/rails" does not exist, so first you need to create a folder named "script" inside your project and paste the file "bin/rails" inside it (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20122117/6705565)).

Now just click with the **Right mouse button** in your project and select "**Run server**".